# std::is_base_of for templated vector function parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, std

I want to provide two different implementations of an `operator>>` depending on whether the given type is a subclass of a special type:

```
class A {};

class B : public A{};
class C {};

template<typename T>
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is,
    std::vector<typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<A, T>::value>::type>& vec)
{
    std::cout << "Special case called" << std::endl;
    return is;
}

template<typename T>
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is,
    std::vector<T>& vec)
{
    std::cout << "General case called" << std::endl;
    return is;
}


void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::vector<A> a;
    std::vector<B> b;
    std::vector<C> c;
    std::stringstream ss("A string");
    ss >> a;
    ss >> b;
    ss >> c;
}
```

Which prints

```
General case called
General case called
General case called
```

Changing the second operator definition to

```
template<typename T>
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is,
    std::vector<typename std::enable_if<!std::is_base_of<A, T>::value>::type>& vec)
{
    std::cout << "General case called" << std::endl;
    return is;
}
```

Does not compile because of

```
error C2678: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::stringstream'
```

So I am probably using `std::enable_if` wrong. But what is correct? Are there problems with the templated `std::vector` here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think the std::enable_if is in the most desired position here, I would put it in the return type to enable SFINAE:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<A, T>::value,std::istream>::type& 
operator>>(std::istream& is,std::vector<T>& vec)
{
    std::cout << "Special case called" << std::endl;
    return is;
}

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_base_of<A, T>::value,std::istream>::type& 
operator>>(std::istream& is,std::vector<T>& vec)
{
    std::cout << "General case called" << std::endl;
    return is;
}
```

[live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dfcba69483153cfb)

Comment: Thank you very much, this solves the problem! I have a short follow-up question: Can I provide a third, explicit, specialization? ``template<> std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, std::vector<std::string>& vec) {...}`` does not compile because of ``error C2794: 'type' : is not a member of any direct or indirect base class of 'std::enable_if<false,std::istream>'``

Comment: @PhilLab prefer overload over function specialization

Comment: duuhhh, I missed the obvious :-). if all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail

Answer (score 2):

@Biggy's answer correctly demonstrates one way to do this properly. Here's an alternative that I find a bit more readable (along with some minor corrections and improvements):

```
template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<A, T>{}, int>::type = 0>
std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& is, std::vector<T>& vec) {
    std::cout << "Special case called\n";
    return is;
}

template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_base_of<A, T>{}, int>::type = 0>
std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& is, std::vector<T>& vec) {
    std::cout << "General case called\n";
    return is;
}
```

<kbd>**[Online Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a12b93261306bef6)**</kbd>

Or better yet, using tag dispatching:

```
template<typename T>
std::istream& impl(std::istream& is, std::vector<T>& vec, std::true_type) {
    std::cout << "Special case called\n";
    return is;
}

template<typename T>
std::istream& impl(std::istream& is, std::vector<T>& vec, std::false_type) {
    std::cout << "General case called\n";
    return is;
}

template<typename T>
std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& is, std::vector<T>& vec) {
    return impl(is, vec, std::is_base_of<A, T>{});
}
```

<kbd>**[Online Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d495aee377ff033)**</kbd>

In practice I've found the latter approach to be much more maintainable when the number of conditions is large, and result in more easily-deciphered error messages.

As to *why your* code doesn't work, the problem is that `std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<A, T>::value>::type` as a parameter type is not a deducible context for `T`, and there is no other parameter involving `T` to aide deduction. So because you don't explicitly specify `T` when you call it, the operator is simply not an eligible candidate to invoke because `T` is not known. When you then put the same attempted-SFINAE in the other overload, *neither* overload is viable and you get your error. A loose rule of thumb is: if you need `typename` (as with the `enable_if` usage), you are no longer in a deducible context.

Putting the `enable_if` in the return type or as a defaulted template parameter instead works because the parameter types (specifically the nice and simple `std::vector<T>&`) are such that `T` is deducible.

Comment: Thank you, especially for the explanation as to *why* it dit not work